# cascading sinkmode.update notworking

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I just started cascading programming and have a cascading job which needs to run variable times of iteration. During each iteration, it ready from file (Tap) generated from previous iteration and write calculated data to two separate SinkTaps.

- One Tap (Tap Final) is used to collect data from each iterations.
- The other Tap (Tap intermediate) using to collect data that need to be calculated in the next iteration.

I am using `SinkMode.UPDATE` for "Tap final" to make this happen. It works correct at local mode. But failed at cluster mode. Complain about file already existed ("Tap final").

I am running CDH4.4 and cascading 2.5.2. Seems like there is no one has experienced the same problem.

If anyone knows any possible way to fix it, please let me know. Thanks

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://dv-db.machines:8020/tmp/xxxx/cluster/97916 already exists
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1269)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1266)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1266)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:601)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:586)
at cascading.flow.hadoop.planner.HadoopFlowStepJob.internalNonBlockingStart(HadoopFlowStepJob.java:105)
at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.blockOnJob(FlowStepJob.java:196)
at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.start(FlowStepJob.java:149)
at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.call(FlowStepJob.java:124)
at cascading.flow.planner.FlowStepJob.call(FlowStepJob.java:43)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to improve the formatting of the question but i believe it is missing some details. Please take another look so that readers can get a full understanding of the issue. Also please add the exact error you are getting and any code samples that might be relevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would helpful to understand the issue better if you could add cascading flow code to your question.

It seems the job file with same name is being used between different jobs on cluster mode. One simple solution in case you are fine to not run it concurrently would be be set max concurrent steps to 1.

```
Flow flow = flowConnector.connect("name", sources, sinks, outPipe1, outPipe2);
flow.setMaxConcurrentSteps(jobProperties, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed it from tap to pipe and everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE only works with sinks (like databases) that support in-place updating.

If you're using Hfs (a file system sink) then you'll need to use SinkMode.REPLACE.